# cannot install reticulate conda environment error

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I'm trying to install reticulate but it's not working, I get this error message : `Error 1 occurred creating conda environment`.
How can I fix this please.

Code :

```
library(reticulate)
repl_python()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reticulate needs an conda or another virtual environment. To investigate the source of the error message, I would check whether and which python version is per default used via  `py_config()`.

if not found, try to re-create the environment via `conda_create("r-reticulate")`.
and then specify which environment to use via `use_condaenv("r-reticulate")`.

Helpful links for installation and setup are [rstudio.github.io/reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/index.html) and subsection on [conda-tools](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/conda-tools.html)

Example output for `py_config()`

```
python:         ~/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      ~/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     ~/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 16 2021, 11:37:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          ~/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.5
```